# React imported Style is not working but bootstrap Style is working

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, loader

I can use style from bootstrap. But when I use import style, it is not working?

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: {
          loader: "css-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

React Code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react"; 
import "./css/accounts.css"; 
export default class Login extends Component { render() { return ( <Fragment> <p className="text-center test" id="test"> Login </p> </Fragment> ); } }
```

Comment: React Code:

    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import "./css/accounts.css";
    
    export default class Login extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
                <p className="text-center test" id="test">
                  Login
                </p>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

This is react code

Comment: Edit the qeustion and add there the react code.\